# Smooth shading interpolation problem when creating new mesh

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to break up a mesh in different pieces.

The problem I'm having is related to material rendering. In my original model, I have smooth shading applied, as you can see in the following capture:

[image]

To break the model in different parts, I'm selecting a set of faces and using `P` to create a new mesh with those parts.

[image]

Once the new mesh is created, the smooth shading interpolation is calculated differently, and you can see the part as a patch:

[image]

This do not happen if instead of using smooth shading I use flat shading.

I think this is because the interpolation done by the shading works differently depending on the complete mesh.

Is there a way to use smooth shading and have all the parts rendering as they would be part of the same mesh?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53749/normals-changed-after-separating-object-in-2-pieces

Comment: The answer given and accepted in the question this supposedly is a duplicated of, only works on a sphere. The comment by the person who made that question even addresses that, but mentions the Data Transfer modifier, which can be the right answer, although it's never fully explained.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I followed the link to the duplicated question but I still do not understand how to make it work. Data Transfer modifier is quite confusing. Can you provide more information on how this can be solved? Thanks!